# Select Excel Rows Containing Word in One Column, Plus > Functions in Multiple Other Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns of data, of which I need to delete all but a certain few desired rows.

Column A has keywords, Column B has Numerical Values, and Column C has numerical values.

I want to make a selection that accomplishes the following:

select all rows where Column A contains (not equals) "keyword", AND column B >x, AND column C >y.

X and Y are, of course, placeholders for any number I would specify.

Thanks

Z

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [advanced filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b).

1. Select the data you want to filter
2. click on data (tab on menu bar)
3. In the sort and filter area click on advanced filter

With the advanced filter you can filter in place or copy result to another place, might be handy if you want to continue to work with the result, but keeping the original.
If you added some of your data, criteria and expected result I could help further.

Comment: Thanks, I had pretty much gotten that far. I was hoping for just a basic example of how it is done. I found my answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7JPZiBhW5Y   Basically, you create additional rows above the data you are trying to sort, with an operator and value in each column you want to sort by.